# Are some users banned?

Tags: discussion

Reading the user's comments (now deleted) on this happy post:
https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/87729/brides-house-informal-relaxed

That just came to my mind. Are some users banned at any given time?

Answer (score 6):

We don't usually ban someone on first offense, but we do like rude or inappropriate comments to be flagged for moderator action. Bans of varying length can be used if there is an escalation or continuation of the behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Users (or more precisely, accounts) can be [put in the penalty box](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/), although for accounts which haven't contributed anything positive to the site, I believe the account is likely to be deleted - that's certainly what happens to the spammers.

Banning a *user* (i.e. a physical person) is a different problem.

Practically, I suspect it's not worth worrying about "one off" incidents - the user joins, dishes out a few choice comments, leaves and never comes back again. Not worth worrying about whether to leave a warning, give a temporary ban, give a permanent ban or whatever as they're not going to visit the site again anyway.